# How to count registry key values using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am using vb.net and I want to count values in windows registry key under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MYAPP`. Using the code below:

```
Dim tempKey As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\MyApp")
Dim count As Integer = tempKey.ValueCount.ToString
```

but I'm getting an error on the second line saying:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Please I need your help.

Comment: Turn on `Option Strict`.  If `Count` is an integer, using `ToString` to assign something to it wont compile.  If there is no "Software\MyApp" entry, the key will be `Nothing`.  Your code doesnt check.

Comment: Your subKey name is probably wrong - use regedit to copy the Key name and remove `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\'  BTW please include the Imports statement and any require non-standard references.

Comment: there was no entry under software\MyApp so I changed my code to include the code to check if it is empty. It is working now. Below is the code added:    If My.Computer.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\MyApp") Is Nothing Then
            Count=0
        Else
            Dim tempKey As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\MyApp")
            Dim count As Integer = tempKey.ValueCount.ToString
        End If